# How To Extract Complex Parcel Numbers & Strings Using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, extract

I was wondering what is the safest and the most efficient way to extract Parcels/AIN Numbers using Reg Exp via PHP.  These parcel numbers are coming from a HUGE text file that are surrounded by addresses, characters and strings. When I use php's reg exp, I dont get any accurate parcels that I want. I'm not sure how to extract the parcel numbers being that they come in a varieties of ways. A snippet of the text, and the regular expression im using is below.

(Parcels usually come in a variety of ways, to many to list here, but here are a few

- 130.1-8-13,
- 01-00603-0000-00002-0000-C-0410,
- 01-0AVB-0000-00002-0000-C-0410,
- 01-00603-0000-00002-0000-BFB-0101,
- 412001216.39-2-22,
- 412089214.-1-3.12,
- 412001216.41-1-12.6,
  )

The php code im currently using..

```
   $pattern = '/[0-9A-Z.\-]{9,30}/';

   $reg_exp = preg_match_all($pattern, 'text below' , $matches,   PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

12020                                                                         200800031620700
412001216.41-1-11.1            JOE JACKSON L               555 EASTERN AVE               BALLSTON SPA, NY 12020                                                                                                       200800059632500
412001216.41-1-11.2            MICHEAL JORDAN              555 YELLOW AVE               BALLSTON SPA, NY 12020                                                                                                       200800007874700
412001216.41-1-12.6            BRITTNEY SPEARS         PO BOX 139                    ESOPUS, NY 12429-0139                                                                                                        200800057794400
412001216.47-2-17              MAROON 5             686 BALLYY AVE              BALLSTON SPA, NY 12020                                                                                                       200800031662900
412001216.48-1-21             LADY J GAGA SMIT           FORNOTX ROBERT                 999 N HIGH ST                 GILLMORE SPA, NY 12020                                                                         200800065014500
412001216.55-1-8               BILLY RODGER LIL JOSEPH A JR

Comment: In order to parse them with a regex we need all the possibilities. Those string you are giving have very little in common. "Parcels usually come in a variety of ways, to many to list here"

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande yes your right, there's way too many possibilities for parcels. I'm not sure if extracting this type of data is possible???

Comment: Since I actually don't know how many parcel formats there are, I can't answer you yet.

Comment: @TitusShoats you can start by enumerating some conditions: starts with a digit? must have a dash? always 9 to 30 chars? any A-Z allowed?

Comment: @Mariano, well theres many possibilities with parcels. Some start with strings or numbers. Some have dashes, some have periods (.) included. All parcels from my experience have capital letters. The minimum length of any parcel is 8 characters, the maximum is around 30. Theres tons of possibilities with parcels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. All of the parcel numbers in the above sample code are preceded by a 15-digit number, so you could do:

```
$pattern = '/\d{15} [\dA-Z.\-]{9,30}/';
```

or if all you want is the second part:

```
$pattern = '/\d{15} ([\dA-Z.\-]{9,30})/';
```

This pattern avoids accidentally grabbing zipcodes like the pattern you were using does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 15 digit, can you please explain??

Comment: thanks, but this expression is still far from accurate.

Comment: as @Mariano said, unless we have more information, we can't help you. the expression I gave you captures all of the parcel codes in the example data you gave us, and doesn't give you any false positives. Can you show me an example of a code that isn't captured by my expression? Then I might be able to tweak it so that it would work.